# how to write onClick (with arguments) optimized by useCallback in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, bind, usecallback

I need to implement a long list, each item in the long list will trigger a new function when onClick, because this function is unchanged every time it is rendered, so I want to use useCallback to optimize it, this returned function Fn needs to pass in parameters, so should I use bind to pass parameters in onClick?

```
    const func = useCallback((num) => setIndex(num), [])
    // myComponent
    <TableItem onClick = { func.bind(null, index) } />
```

This is my first question, please forgive me if something is wrong，Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you pass a callback to multiple components then you can use useCallback in the following way:

```js
//make Counter a pure component (only re renders if something changed)
const Counter = React.memo(function Counter({
  counter,
  up,
  index,
}) {
  // ok to do onClick={new=>'function'} because we do not pass
  // onClick to sub components unless counter changes
  console.log('rendering index:', index);
  return (
    <button onClick={() => up(index)}>{counter}</button>
  );
});
const App = () => {
  //fixed amount of items that does not re order so can use index
  //  in key, do not use index as key when you don't have fixed
  //  amount of items or re order the list.
  const [counters, setCounters] = React.useState([0, 0]);
  const up = React.useCallback(
    (index) =>
      //pass callback to setCounters so counters is not
      //  a dependency of useCallback
      setCounters((counters) =>
        counters.map((counter, i) =>
          i === index ? counter + 1 : counter
        )
      ),
    []//empty dependency, only created when App mounts
  );
  return (
    <ul>
      {counters.map((counter, index) => (
        <Counter
          up={up}
          counter={counter}
          key={index}
          index={index}
        />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the second param in useCallback, this will prevent multiple renders.

i.e., if you want to set it just in when the component starts you can set

```
useCallback((num => setIndex(num)), [])
```

Note that [], it means it will only render at the beginning, if you want to update it when any variable changes, you can set [variablename, ...]

Also, I think you don't need the func.bind, you can set only

```
<Component onClick={func}/>
```

Edit: I misunderstood this question.

If you want to send a param in the onClick you can set it like this

```
const func = useCallback((num => setIndex(num)), [])
<Component onClick={()=>func(yourParam)}/>
```

With this way your onClick will always use the function, but it allows a param that you can set anywhere

Comment: I know what you are talking about, I think you may have misunderstood what I meant, and I want to ask whether the way of passing parameters like onClick is reasonable and whether there is a more elegant way

Comment: my function func must need to incoming parameters

Comment: Yep, I misunderstood it, I have edited my answer, I think you only has to change  the value with a param, creating an "outside function"

Comment: If you use the arrow function, then each render will re-create a new function, then the optimization of useCallback is meaningless. Then the performance of the mobile terminal will be poor

Comment: If `onClick={()=>func(yourParam)}` is in the same component as `const func = useCallback((num => setIndex(num)), [])` it defeats the purpose of useCallback

Comment: I know how to solve it, I can achieve my purpose by storing the function in the object generated by useRef, thank you